# Access inner join data from sequelize using include

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to join two tables using Sequelize's include as such:

```
  models.user.findAll({include: {model: models.boardMember, required:true}})
    .then(function(board) {
       console.log(board);
       res.render('contact', { title: 'Kontakt', board: board });
    });
```

My models look like this using the [sequelize express example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example):

User (it doesn't quite feel right having the hasMany here instead of in boardMembers, but I didn't want to have the foreign key field in the users table)

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    //lots of normal user fields(username, password, access...
   }, {
     classMethods: {
       associate: function(models) {
         user.hasMany(models.boardMember, {
           foreignKey: {
             allowNull: false
           }
         });
       }
     }
  });

  return user;
};
```

boardMember

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var boardMember = sequelize.define('boardMember', {
    post: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: false,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
  return boardMember;
};
```

I then want to access the data returned in a table using handlebars:

```
{{#each board}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{boardMembers.post}}</td>
    <td>{{firstName}} {{surName}}</td>
    <td>{{email}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Here is where I get it wrong(I think). The names and email appear, but not the post. I've tried using only post as well but to no avail. This is odd I think because the query that is generated looks like this (I removed the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns to make it shorter for you to read):

```
SELECT 
    `user`.`id`, `user`.`username`, `user`.`password`, 
    `user`.`firstName`, `user`.`surName`, `user`.`email`, `user`.`access`,  
    `boardMembers`.`id` AS `boardMembers.id`, `boardMembers`.`post` AS `boardMembers.post`,  
    `boardMembers`.`userId` AS `boardMembers.userId` 
FROM 
    `users` AS `user` 
INNER JOIN 
    `boardMembers` AS `boardMembers` ON `user`.`id` = `boardMembers`.`userId`;
```

The console.log outputs something like this(the data obviously changed):

```
[ Instance {
dataValues:
 { id: 2,
   username: 'username',
   password: 'hashedPassword',
   firstName: 'User',
   surName: 'Name',
   email: 'user@name.com',
   access: '0',
   boardMembers: [Object] },
...
]
```

Any help is **much** appreciated!

Thanks,

Freece

Answer (score 0):

Per the [sequelize documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance) the value for the include attribute is a list.

You can try with the special value `include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]` and see if it works for you.

Additionally you have a problem with your template becuase you have stablished a one to many relation and therefore the `boardMemebers` attribute of model instances are arrays.

Comment: Hmm sorry to say it didn't work. Tried using this: 'models.user.findAll({include: [{nested:true, all:true, model: models.boardMember, required:true}]})' and a few different versions of it. Thank you for the tip though!

Comment: specifying the model is not needed if you use the all: true option. And from what i can see from your question you are retrieving the related boardMemebers (the `boardMembers: [Object]` on response array) but in your template you are treating the boardMember attribute as if it where a single object but the relation is multiple

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have been thinking of this the wrong way. I have realized that what I need to do is create a custom helper for HandleBars.